# Cannot insert a command button

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2002

I followed this step-by-step tutorial to insert a button into an Excel sheet:
http://www.excelbeispiele.de/Schaltflaeche.htm (It's German, but the pictures speak for themselves.)

However, steps 2. to 3. don't work for me:

*Edit not from OP to include image and translation:*

[image: SU607712 question example]

Instead I get the message "Can't insert object".

I already changed macro settings to low security, and closed and opened the file again.

What else can I do?

**Edit:** You can see a translation of the entire page at [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.excelbeispiele.de/Schaltflaeche.htm&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://www.excelbeispiele.de/Schaltflaeche.htm%26biw%3D1024%26bih%3D577). 
It’s incomplete –– it doesn’t translate the word “Schaltfläche”.

Comment: please describe what step 2 and 3 are

Comment: Which version of Windows? Perhaps your common controls DLL is corrupt/missing. You're still using Office XP? Can't you update to a newer version?